# Google Apps Script - how to update scripts attached to many spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a script for a spreadsheet template. My user makes copies from the spreadsheet template and the attached script. There are many such instances both spreadsheet and the script. When I update the script for the spreadsheet template, I(or my user) have to manually update all scripts attached to spreadsheets. All scripts are the same. Is there a way to synchronize the script update automatically?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is maintain a single **standalone** script and publish it as a library instead of having it reside in the spreadsheet template. This way, you have to change the script in only one place. 
To work with triggers such as onOpen, onEdit etc. you can have shell functions in your spreadsheet template. Something like

```
function onOpen(e){
  LibraryName.onOpen(e);
}
```

Comment: what about user permission, active user or owner? The owner of the library is me, but it should be owner of the customer, running as the customer...

Comment: For example, in library there is MailApp sending error message to predefined email address, is the sender the owner of the library or the owner of the script using the library? What I want is the owner of the script.